# How to pass data from child route to parent (using form on submit)

Tags: angular

I have a component which contains a list of expenses with a *New Expense* button. On click it will go to its child route like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="['./new']">New Expense</a>
```

This New Expense Component is a form that takes user input and creates a new expense. Then it uses a service to add it to the database.

The issue is the `ExpensesComponent` (The one with the list) does not update, because it only checks the database to populate the expense list initially through `ngOnInit()` .

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.expenseService.getExpenses()
    .subscribe(expenses => this.expenses = expenses);
  }
```

Examples online I have seen have the input in same component as the form so they can simply 'push' it into the list after they use an http post request to add it to the database, so that it also visually updates "in place".

My goal is to replicate this effect. I want to add it the list so that the user can see it, not only post it into the database. Is there a way to send this Expense from the child route to the parent or should I add to the database and have the `ExpensesComponent` reload the list instead of having that only happen during `ngOnInit()`? Below is what I believe is the relevant code. I removed some stuff from it to remove clutter, so it won't actually run. I'm more so just looking for what is the best approach, not really the code.

I know for example if in the template I did not use a route, but just called the child component like this `<app-new-expenses></app-new-expenses>`. There is a way to do it with emitters, so was I wrong therefore to use route to display this component?

**Expense Component** which houses the list:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-expenses',
    templateUrl: './expenses.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./expenses.component.css']
})

export class ExpensesComponent implements OnInit {

    expenses: Expense[];

    constructor(private expenseService: ExpenseService) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.expenseService.getExpenses()
            .subscribe(expenses => this.expenses = expenses);
    }

    getExpense(id: number) {
        //console.log(this.expenseService.getExpense(id));
    }

}
```

**New Expense Component** which contains the form:

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'app-new-expense',
    templateUrl: './new-expense.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./new-expense.component.css']
})
export class NewExpenseComponent implements OnInit {

    model: Expense;
    types: string[];

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private expenseService: ExpenseService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.model = new Expense(0, 40, "Virgin Mobile", "2019/10/12", "Fixed");
        this.types = ['Fixed', 'Periodic', 'Variable'];
    }

    onSubmit(amount, place, date) {
        var expense = new Expense(6, amount, place, date, "Fixed");
        this.expenseService.addExpense(expense).subscribe(

        );
    }
}
```

**Expense Service**:

```js
@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ExpenseService {

    expenses$: Observable<Expense[]>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getExpenses(): Observable<Expense[]> {
        this.expenses$ = this.http.get<Expense[]>('http://localhost:8000/expenses');
        return this.expenses$;
    }

    addExpense(expense: Expense): Observable<Expense> {
        return this.http.post<Expense>("http://localhost:8000/expenses", expense);
    }

    getExpense(id: number | string) {
        return this.getExpenses().pipe(
            map((expenses: Expense[]) => expenses.find(expense => expense.id === +id))
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can modify your service to retain the list of expenses.

Here is an example of one of my services that does this. This also notifies the components that the "selected product" should change to the newly added product in the list.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
    private productsUrl = 'api/products';
    private products: IProduct[];

    private selectedProductSource = new BehaviorSubject<IProduct | null>(null);
    selectedProductChanges$ = this.selectedProductSource.asObservable();

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

    getProducts(): Observable<IProduct[]> {
        if (this.products) {
            return of(this.products);
        }
        return this.http.get<IProduct[]>(this.productsUrl)
                        .pipe(
                            tap(data => console.log(JSON.stringify(data))),
                            tap(data => this.products = data),
                            catchError(this.handleError)
                        );
    }

    createProduct(product: IProduct, headers: HttpHeaders): Observable<IProduct> {
      return this.http.post<IProduct>(this.productsUrl, product,  { headers: headers} )
                    .pipe(
                        tap(data => console.log('createProduct: ' + JSON.stringify(data))),
                        tap(data => {
                            this.products.push(data);
                        }),
                        catchError(this.handleError)
                    );
}
}
```

Notice that the `createProduct` method then pushes the data into the list.

You can find the complete code here: https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-Communication/tree/master/APM-Final

Alternatively, you can look into NgRx, which is a state management library for Angular.

Comment: Awesome stuff as always from @DeborahK :) I have a suggestion or question, don't you think it would be best to move what is essentially a caching functionality outside of the service and catch it via an interceptor. This might allow for a thinner class and a reusable functionality for any caching needs.

Comment: Thank you for the kind words! Regarding an interceptor. Yes. Brice Wilson builds one in his Pluralsight course here: https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/angular-http-communication

Comment: Answer worked perfectly. Initialized my expenses variable as type Expense[] instead of Observable<Expense[]> and slightly adjusted my getExpenses() method so that in my addExpense() method I could do something like this.expenses.push(expense). Also thank you for the selected expense tip.

Comment: @DeborahK, your pluralsite course helped me to keep my knowledge up-to-date with Angular and currently I am working as a full-stack Angular + .NET developer to the Australian government because of you. With this post, you enlightened me one more time. Thank you very much.